# Magento 2: SMS Integration REST API

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api

I have an API URL of SMS Gateway :

```
https://smsexample.net/test/api.php?username=xxxx&password=xxxx&from=xxxx&to=xxxx&text=xxxx
```

How can I make REST API using this gateway, so can call the API in my mobile app?

Comment: If you want to try https://magecomp.com/magento-2-sms-notification.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call this rest API in code on each event of your requirement like New order, order update, Here are the ways you can use this API:

Solution 1 :

Go into code, Place API in code of each event Ex. Checkout, Order Update which require code knowledge in deep.

Solution 2:

There are free sms notification modules available for magento like "Spring Edge Magento sms extension" which is Compatible with: Magento versions 1.x and 2.x

Magento sms module events configuration :

- Send sms to customer and admin on new order is placed.
- When order status is set to hold.
- When order status is set to Unhold.
- When order is cancelled.
- When order status is set Shipment.

http://springedge.com/magento-sms-extension-module-free.html

Comment: @Jsparo30 please upvote if it helped you.

Comment: Done. Thank you ...

Comment: @Jsparo30 if you have sms extension from springedge then please send me, i need this for magento2